# php header function produces an error when it shouldnt

Tags: php, header

Im working with PHP 4.3.11 and when I execute a [header](http://ar.php.net/header) always responds with an error like this

**Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at d:\folder\file.php:1) in **d:\folder\file.php** on line **2**

**Warning:** Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at d:\folder\file.php:1) in **d:\folder\file.php** on line **3**
Current PHP version: 4.3.11

the code I used to generate this error was

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");   // Date in the past

    echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();

    // prints e.g. '2.0' or nothing if the extension isn't enabled
    echo phpversion('tidy');
?>
```

It has no spaces nor newlines before or after the php tags, and the same code in a 5.x version returns just the php version as expected.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
Solved!: I've opened the file with western european encoding and deleted the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) and it worked. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a [UTF BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark) at the start of the file?

Comment: Thanks! I've checked with another editor and dropped those chars and it worked !!!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that there are no empty lines and invisible characters (such as the [UTF BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)) before the PHP block so that `<?php` is really the first in the file.

Comment: thanks for your fast response, but it doesnt, its really making me crazy :|

Answer (score 2):

if your file does not contain anything else but php code it is recommended to skip the php closing tag to avoid empty spaces issue at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that your entire script (other files included) are sending some output before the header() function is called.

You should revise all your files and see if any of them is outputting something (with echo() or print()), or if you missed some empty spaces after the last closing tag **?>**

Comment: the error is produced even if I execute the file directly, other executions should return the same because they're made using ajax.

Comment: Like @solomongaby says, you should skip the closing tag entirely. It is allowed in PHP, and doing so lets you avoid problems with trailing whitespace/linefeed

Answer (score 0):

it's unlikely, but there's the possibility to define auto_prepend_file in the php.ini (probably .htaccess too).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php - this acts like a `require()` at the beginning of every script. you can check this by looking at the `phpinfo();` output.

but i too think the problem is the utf-8 BOM.